# How to pass $scope variable data into node.js backend server file?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have json data in $scope variable and i want to use that $scope variable inside my backend app.js node file.

This is my backend file app.js:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {

    var XLSX = require('xlsx');
    var workbook = XLSX.readFile('./uploads/' + req.file.filename);
    var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
    var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
    //var values = [];
    console.log(data);
    return res.status(200).send(data);
});

app.post('/api/uploadlast',api.addNewContact, function(req,res){

    Contact.bulkCreate(excels).then(function(users) {
        return res.status(200).send(users);
    }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function(err) {
        return res.status(422).send(err.errors[0].message);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
})
```

This is my controller file:

```
   $scope.uploadFile = function() {
            var file = $scope.myFile;
            var uploadUrl = "/upload";
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);

            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    }
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    //$state.reload();
                    $scope.excels = response.data;
                    console.log("success!!");
                })
                .catch(function() {
                    console.log("error!!");
                });

        }

        $scope.uploadLast = function() {
            $http.post('/api/uploadlast').then(function(response) {
                $state.reload();
           });
        }
     })
```

I want to get $scope.excels data into my backend to bulkcreate into databases.

Comment: **Describe the problem.** Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: i have data in $scope.excels so i want to post that data my backend

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: You pass the data to your backend in the `upload` request. Do the similar thing for the `uploadlast`. You can refer the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post.

Comment: @georgeawg i am not getting "excels" values in my backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any data with a post request as the second parameter of [$http.post()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post). So you can do something like:

```
$scope.uploadLast = function() {
    var data = {
        excels: $scope.excels
    };

    $http.post('/api/uploadlast', data).then(function(response) {
        $state.reload();
    });
}
```

And in your backend, you can access it like:

```
app.post('/api/uploadlast',api.addNewContact, function(req, res){

    var data = req.body.excels;


    Contact.bulkCreate(data).then(function(users) {
        return res.status(200).send(users);
    }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function(err) {
        return res.status(422).send(err.errors[0].message);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
});
```